# found nil while unwrapping optional

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a simple application that consists of one Navigation controller with 2 screens controlled by a single UIViewController class. The app will allow the user to enter a number from 0 to 10 in a text field and when the user presses a button they will be taken to the 2nd screen showing if they guessed the randomly generated number. I get the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error when I am accessing the text property of the label in the second screen. I dont uderstand why, I have connected the label with the class. Any suggetions?

This is my UI: 
[image]

This is my Navigation controller class code:

```
class MyNavController: UINavigationController {
var ranNum:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ranNum = (Int)(arc4random_uniform(10))

    NSLog("random number: \(ranNum)")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

This is my Generic View controller class:

```
class GenericViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

var setThisLabel: String = "You Win!"

@IBAction func guessTheNumber(sender: AnyObject) {
    var generatedRanNumber = (parentViewController as! MyNavController).ranNum
    var userGuessNumer = inputTextField.text.toInt()

    if generatedRanNumber == userGuessNumer {
        outputLabel.text = "You Win!"
    } else if generatedRanNumber < userGuessNumer {
        outputLabel.text = "Think Less..."
    } else {
        outputLabel.text = "Think Big..."
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: "found will while unwrapping optional". Who's Will, and why did you find him while you were unwrapping an optional? :) (I'm guessing you meant "found **nil** while unwrapping optional.")

Comment: ha, I see the misspelt word now :D. Will chage it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is you are pushing from one instance of Generic View Controller to another without passing on the data. It is generally not recommended to use a generic subclass of UIViewController in this way. If you want your code to work as is, place the UILabel in the same view as your other UI and don't segue (i.e. only have one instance of GenericViewController). Or create two subclasses of UIViewController one called "GuessViewController" and the other called "AnswerViewController" and pass the guess value between them in prepareForSegue. GuessViewController would handle getting the string from the user and evaluate it. AnswerViewController would whether it's right or wrong. It is also generally not necessary to subclass UINavigationController. You could place that code in the viewDidLoad of GuessViewController.

Comment: you are right with some of your suggestions. but i would not say that **this is actually the problem** that causes "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"... :)

Comment: I put all of his code in Xcode and only got error with segue.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will give it a try now. :)

Comment: yeah. my bad. i overlooked something... :)

Comment: It did work perfectly using the prepareforsegue + using two different instances for the two screens. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

change from

```
var generatedRanNumber = (parentViewController as! MyNavController).ranNum
```

to

```
var generatedRanNumber = (navigationController as! MyNavController).ranNum
```

also notice that `arc4random_uniform(10)` returns a number between 0 and 9. you tell the user to guess a number between 0 and 10.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did the change but the problem still exists :/ I will try to create two different classes of UIViewController and use the prepareForSeguey method. as -beyowulf suggested